# Deny URL sequence in Scrapy CrawalSpider

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy spider that crawals websites for social contacts. I want it to deny urls containing "/products", "/collections" etc.
This is my LinkExtractor rule.

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=allowed_domains),
         callback='parse_page', process_links='process_links', follow=True),
)
```

I've checked many solutions but I can't use them in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suppose to work:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=allowed_domains, deny=('/products/*','/collections/*', )),
         callback='parse_page', process_links='process_links', follow=True),
)
```

You can see an [example](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example) in the scrapy documentation